# Unable to run java from CMD

Tags: java, cmd

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... I'm following several YouTube videos and I'm still unable to run my java program from the command prompt.

VERY first thing I did in cmd was:
set path="[copied URL to the JDK bin directory]"

Then I used 'cd' to get all the way to my homework directory, containing 4 java files.

Then I typed in 'javac hangman.java' to compile it... (Let's just say it was hangman)

Finally, I typed in 'java hangman'

And it says: "Error: Could not find or load main class hangman" inside my cmd.

What have I done wrong?

(I'm using Windows 10 if this somehow makes a difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure your class name starts with capital letter, `Hangman` instead of `hangman`.
2. Make sure you have `public static void main(String[] args)` method

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize it was case sensitive because it was compiling my work when I typed it in lowercase... This fixed my problem, I'll accept this answer in about 7 minutes when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

1. First you have to indicate where the java file is.
   But if you are in the same directory as your class to compile => error not find main class.
2. javac namefile.javac
3. java namefile

For exemple, I want to compile Car.java and its path is: Desktop > CarsProyects > src > carsPackage.

if I'll try: 
cd Desktop
cd CarsProyects
cd src
cd carsPackage
javac Cars.java
java Cars

I would have the same error as you 'main class not load or not find' 
So try this one (cd carsPackage >.. ):

cd Desktop
cd CarsProyects
cd src
javac Cars.java
java Cars

I hope this help!

Comment: I am new to java. I have problem running java from cmd. My directory is C:\Users\wo\Desktop. I successfully compiled HelloWorld program. I am unable to run the program from cmd. I get the error : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld @Jessica

Answer (score 1):

The CMD has specific case sensitivities.

When finding directories make sure the 1st letter of the filename is capitalized

> Filename

All parameters must be accurate for java methods including the

> main